# "Mailing" tab won't disappear after disabling CiviMail component

Tags: civimail

Shouldn't the "Mailing" tab in the navigation disappear when I disable the CiviMail component in the administrator settings?

Because I can still see it, after I disabled the component and I get a access error when I click on a drop down link of the tab.

CiviCRM version:4.6.8CMS version:Drupal 7.39MySQL version:5.0.10PHP version:5.4.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug - I was able to reproduce it as well. Normally disabling a component *should* hide the menu items associated with it.
If this is important to you, you could try to figure out what's going wrong and submit a pull-request with the code to fix it, or else provide funding to fix it in the [paid issue queue](https://civicrm.org/paid-issue-queue). Unfortunately the core team doesn't have capacity to fix non-critical bugs unless someone provides code or funding.

Answer (score 1):

There is a specific admin menu for setting up the display of the menu. It is located under **Administer menu > Customize Data and Screens > Display Preferences**.

Comment: Thanks, I knew about this feature, but it's still weird that the nav menu entry is still there after I disabled the component.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a cache/session issue.

Did you logout/login after you disabled the component?

X+

Comment: I cleared the cache and tried it even with another browser. It's still there.

Answer (score 0):

This bug also exists with civicrm 4.6.8 inside jooomla 3.4.4.

The suggested solution in setting up Display preferences for contacts does ot change the issue: Mailings is in the civicrm menu while it is de-activated.
As a minor point: The error message is ugly, terminates the civicrm component and returns the user to the control-panel of Joomla.

ps: just saw that it is possible to delete the menu-item in another screen: navigation menu.